# Firebase alone or Firebase and Redis for performance tuning and real time functionalities?

Tags: sql-server, database, firebase, redis

guys.

We have this product in ASP.NET MVC (mobile app and web app) using AWS RDS MsSQL (~ 50 tables) and we are rewriting the product in Angular2 (and Ionic 2 for the mobile version).

Since it's a centralized application I am really concerned about performance (It's not currently a big issue. But I`d prefer address that now before is too late).

Needs:

- Chat (realtime)
- Notifications (realtime)
- List/show 2 main entities/tables (Products and Orders) really fast.

**What would be the best database approach to achieve this (keep in mind I already have a relational database with ~ 50 tables)?**

---

I came up with some alternatives but I am not really sure about them:

1. Keep our RDS MsSQL for inserts/updates and use a tool (like Zapier) to 
   sync with our new Firebase database to get realtime updates (chat and notifications). But will Firebase be as fast as Redis would?
2. Migrate the whole MsSQL database to Firebase (sql to nosql). This is a very dramatic step, so I need to be very sure about that. What about writing latency in nosql databases?
3. Keep our MsSQL (for inserts and updates) and Firebase (for Chat and real time notifications) AND use Redis (AWS ElastiCache to be more precise) just to list/show Products and Orders (using Zapier for sync this mess). Sounds expensive.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: point 1 -> it depends. How are you going to use firebase ? If you plan to move a lot of data, firebase may to be the best option.
point 2 -> no way !
point 3 -> premature optimisation...

which queries do you predict will be to slow in the near future ?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET MVC project, [AZURE Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/) maybe to be better option.